# PyCharm does not stop at breakpoints inside other threat than main threat

Tags: python, multithreading, pycharm, ide

I have a Python multithreaded code like this:

```
import concurrent.futures
import time

# Define a function to simulate a task that takes some time to complete
def some_task(seconds):
    print(f"Starting task that will take {seconds} seconds...")
    time.sleep(seconds)
    print(f"Task completed after {seconds} seconds")

# Create a ThreadPoolExecutor with 3 worker threads
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=3) as executor:
    # Submit multiple tasks to the executor
    task1 = executor.submit(some_task, 2)
    task2 = executor.submit(some_task, 4)
    task3 = executor.submit(some_task, 1)

    # Wait for all tasks to complete and print their results
    results = concurrent.futures.wait([task1, task2, task3], return_when=concurrent.futures.ALL_COMPLETED)
    for result in results.done:
        print(result.result())
```

I set a breakpoint inside function `some_task`, but Pycharm doesn't stop there. However, it stops in the main threat if I put the breakpoint in there.

Answer (score 0):

This happened also to me in recent pycharm (2022 & 2023) and it was because I had previously activated the "Gevent compatible" option. It started working after I deactivated it.

[image]

Other responses mention enabling breakpoints for All threads or patching pydevd, but that was not my case.